# Regular expression to get characters before brackets or comma

Tags: java, regex

I'm pulling my hair out a bit with this.

Say I have a string `7f8hd::;;8843fdj fls "": ] fjisla;vofje]]} fd)fds,f,f`

I want to now extract this `7f8hd::;;8843fdj fls "":` from the string based on the premise that the string ends with either a `}` or `]` or `,` or `)` but all those characters could be present I only need the first one.

I have tried without success to create a regular expression with a Matcher and Pattern class but I just can't seem to get it right.

The best I could come up with is below but my reg exp just doesn't seem to work like I think it should.

```
String line = "7f8hd::;;8843fdj fls "": ] fjisla;vofje]]} fd)fds,f,f";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\}|(.*?)\\]|(.*?)\\)|(.*?),").matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

I'm clearly not understanding reg exp correctly. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^[^\]}),]*
```

matches from the start of the string until (but excluding) the first `]`, `}`, `)` or `,`.

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[^\\]}),]*");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

(You can actually remove the backslashes (`[^]}),]`), but I like to keep them there for clarity and for compatibility since not all regex engines recognize that idiom.)

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Match the start of the string
[^\]}),]* # Match zero or more characters except ], }, ) or ,
```

Comment: you forgot the comma. :) add it pls.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Simple and to the point. You didn't add the comma case as stated in the question but that was trivial to work out.

Comment: ^[^\]}),]* worked for me. Needed to remove everything before a bracket, so I used ^[^\(]*

Answer (score 3):

you could just cut the rest part by `replaceAll`:

```
  String newStr = yourStr.replaceAll("[\\])},].*", "");
```

or by `split()` and get the first element.

```
String newStr = yourStr.split("[\\])},]")[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this (as java string):

```
"(.+?)[\\]},)].*"
```

here is a [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/a1y06)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the regular expression `(.*?)[}\]),](.*?)` I tested it on rubular and worked against your example.